# C/C++ overwriting array bounds

Tags: c++, c

What is a good way to detect bugs where I overwrite an array bound?

```
int a[100];
for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++) a[i] = i;
```

It would be helpful to collect a list of different strategies that people have used in their experience to uncover bugs of this type.
For example, doing a backtrace on from the point of the memory fault (for me often this doesn't work because the stack has been corrupted).

Comment: In C++ use `std::vector` and make sure your implementation has bound checking directive (or use `std::vector::at`).

Comment: @TheBoat: You need to decide whether you're using C or C++. Despite their syntactical similarities, these are actually very different languages with different paradigms and styles. What's good practice in C, is often frowned upon in C++, and I suspect it's vice versa.

Comment: Good points. But, often you inherit code which uses the structure above, so I guess I was looking for shortcuts to debug this kind of problem. Suggestions below to use valgrind is definitely worth trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Static code analysis (e.g. lint)
- Runtime memory analysis (e.g. valgrind)
- Avoid fixed-size buffers, prefer dynamically sized containers
- Use sizeof() instead of magic numbers whenever you can

Comment: All good advice, but one gripe: Container classes are all well and good, but they will only catch this sort of error if you ensure you use e.g. `at()` instead of `[]` *everywhere*.

Comment: Container classes, at least in some implementations, also check [] access in "debug mode". Additionally, container classes encourage use of .size(), which is the core of the described problem

Comment: `std/boost::array` also has the `at()` method. Dynamically sized containers are not always better.

Answer (score 6):

Valgrind will spot this sort of thing pretty reliably!

Answer (score 6):

Use a std::vector, and either use .at() -which always checks ranges - or use[] and turn on range checking in your compiler.

Edit - if you a c++ compiler there is NO reason not to use std::vector. It is no slower than an array (if you turn off bounds checking) and you can use exactly the same loops with .size() and [] - you don't need to be scared off by complex iterators

Comment: Note that `std::vector` is only available in C++, not C.

Comment: @andrew, didn't see the'c' tag

Comment: He can also use `std::array` if he wants it to be sized at compile time only.

Comment: Isn't std::array TR1, how is support outside gcc?

Comment: it's `tr1` supported by gcc and Visual C++, and it's also C++0X.

Answer (score 2):

Write unit tests and run them under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Such bugs are relatively easy caught at the unit test level.

Overwriting end of array is an undefined behaviour, and as such the compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic.

Some static analysis tool might help, but sometimes they give a false alarm.

Answer (score 1):

Some good suggestions here.

Here's some more, especially for C-style code rather than C++:

- Avoid certain unsafe string and memory functions.  In particular, if a function writes to a buffer and doesn't let you specify a size, don't use it.
  Examples for functions to avoid: `strcpy`, `strcat`, `sprintf`, `gets`, `scanf("%s", ptr)`.  Anywhere these are used are red flags.  Instead use things like `memcpy`, `strncpy` (or better yet, `strlcpy`, though not available everywhere), `snprintf`, `fgets`.
- When writing your own interfaces, you should always be able to answer the question: how big are the buffers I'm using?  Usually this means keeping a parameter to track the size, for example as `memcpy` does.

Answer (score 1):

While using STL containers like `vector` is best, there are some handy idioms for controlling this kind of thing, such as this one that I've used quite a bit.

```
int a[100];
const size_t A_SIZE = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

for ( int i = 0; i < A_SIZE; ++i )...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just dynamically allocate memory for you arrays and use exception handling to figure out if you have enough room.

Comment: 1. Use dynamic allocation and exceptions 2. ??? 3. PROFIT! -- Using these things can help, but you have to know what you're doing.  Misusing them and being careless can get you into more pain than you started with.